# IE10 Developer tool's disable menu has script greyed out

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10, ie-developer-tools

In my developer tools in IE 1- 32 bit, in disable menu - script is greyed out.
[image: Screenshot]

What can be the reason for this?

Comment: Do you have any other add ons running?

Answer (score 0):

From [Tim Wappat's blog post](http://www.timwappat.info/post/2009/11/17/e2809cDisable-Scripte2809d-option-greyed-out-in-IE-developer-tools), IE10 added security; add your site to the Trusted Sites:

1. Tools -> Internet Options -> Security -> Trusted Sites -> Sites
   button, type in your domain, click Add. Close. OK.
2. Refresh your page.
3. Developer tools -> Disable -> Script should be an option now.

Comment: Okay. How I can recreate the graying in a clients browser? The thing is a certain selenium test only works on my browser and I guessing it is because of these security settings.

Comment: @HarshNisar if you are asking how to disable scripts from the _Developer Tools -> Disable menu_ on a client's browser, try having them remove the domain from *Trusted Sites*, add the domain to *Restricted Sites* and drag the security level slider for Restricted Sites up to *High*.